# how to sort an expression with descending coefficients?

Tags: expression-manipulation, sorting

I have an expression for example

> ```
> psi = 0.24 FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1] + 0.23 FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1] + 0.5 FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1] + 0.25 FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]
> ```

I wonder how to get the expression with coefficients sorted in descending, such as

> ```
> psi = 0.5 FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1] + 0.25 FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]+ 0.24 FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1] + 0.23 FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1]
> ```

Or get the list as

> `{{0.5,FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1]}, {0.25, FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]}, {0.24,FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1]}, {0.23, FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1]}}`

---

What I only can do is just to extract the coefficients:

```
psi = 0.24 FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1] + 0.23 FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1] + 0.5 FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1] + 0.25 FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]
FCoefficients[HoldPattern[+z__]] := {z}
FCoefficients[else_] := {else}`
```

Now I extract all the terms:

```
ListCoefficients = FCoefficients[targetstate]
```

The output is :

```
{0.24 FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1], 0.23 FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1], 0.5 FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1], 0.25 FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]}
```

What I want now is to sort the coefficients and its corresponding terms from ListCoefficients in descending. I can get the descending coefficients:

```
cofnum = ListCoefficients /. {FF1[l1_] FF2[l2_] FF3[l3_] -> 1};
Sort[cofnum, Greater]
```

The out put is:

```
{0.5, 0.25, 0.24, 0.23}
```

Is there any good way to do get `psi = 0.5 FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1] + 0.25 FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]+ 0.24 FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1] + 0.23 FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1]` ?

Or is it possible to get something as following:

> `{{0.5,FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1]}, {0.25, FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1]}, {0.24,FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1]}, {0.23, FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1]}}`

If anyone knows how to do that, would be very cool if you can give me some hints. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Also, your last comment about using Total will not work... if you apply Total to the list it will sort the terms in a way you don't want.

Comment: yes, you are right. The total doesn't not work. Sorry, I didn't check further. I will change the question.

Comment: @bills, because I want to pick up the three terms with large coefficients

Comment: Might be this: `SortBy[List @@ psi, First] // Reverse`?

Comment: @FredSimons, wow, thanks a lot. With `SortBy[List @@ psi, First] // Reverse`, I get the `{0.5 FF1[1] FF2[0] FF3[1], 0.25 FF1[1] FF2[1] FF3[1], 
 0.24 FF1[0] FF2[1] FF3[-1], 0.23 FF1[0] FF2[0] FF3[1]}`, cool!

Comment: Sorry, I thought my question might be stupid (what if the coefficients are complex or negative, how to sort based on their absolute value?). I figure it out the question and so I delete :-(.  What I do is using the same as you suggested and then in addition do the Abs[] for  the coefficients of each term. Using Ordering to get the index and rearrange the early list. @FredSimons